# Fish Shell argparse Doing Something Very Unexpected

Tags: shell, parsing, arguments, fish

I'm running fish 3.1.0 on OS X 10.14.5.

I am new to fish and to argparse. I like them both.

The following simple test code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fish

function afoo 
    set -l options (fish_opt -s h -l help)
    set options $options (fish_opt -s m -l max --required-val)
    set options $options (fish_opt -s n -l nnn --optional-val)

    argparse $options -- $argv

    echo "max" $_flag_max
    echo "nnn" $_flag_nnn
end
```

Should create two switches m and n. m *must* take a value while n *can* take a value.

Here is a simple screen grab when testing that rudimentary function in Terminal's CLI:

```
[/usr/local/bin/fish 3.1.0] ~ afoo -m foo -n baz
max foo
nnn
[/usr/local/bin/fish 3.1.0] ~ afoo -mfoo -nbaz
max foo
nnn baz
[/usr/local/bin/fish 3.1.0] ~
```

Why does argparse *not* parse the space between the -n switch and its parameter but it *does* parse the space between the -m switch and its parameter?

This is driving me nuts. I've read the documentation a dozen times. What am I doing wrong?

P.S. The order of the switches doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does argparse not parse the space between the -n switch and its parameter but it does parse the space between the -m switch and its parameter?

The `-n` takes an *optional* parameter. Those have to, by getopt convention, be directly attached to the option argument.

Look at e.g.

```
echo never | grep --color never
```

This won't disable color, instead it will set color to *auto* (the default no-argument value) and look for the string "never". So it will show you "never" in red. Instead you'd have to use `--color=never` (or if it had a short option "-c" then "-cnever" would also be acceptable).

Argparse acts like the usual unix getopt(3) option parsing, which it also uses under the covers, because that's how the rest of the system acts.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `n/nnn=?` has an **optional** parameter, whereas `m/max=` has a **required** one. Those strings are the output of your calls to `fish_opt`.

Non-option arguments are stored in `$argv` after a successful run of `argparse`. So your `baz` ends up in `$argv`.